# What is this on line one of my sublime text editor and what is the shortcut to remove it?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am a relatively new programmer and have been exploring the sublime text 3 text editor. I pressed something that I did not mean to and now I have this bar at the top of my markup page. Any help would be appreciated. See attached photo for reference: 
[image]

Comment: Are you saying there is a literal rectangle at the top of the view?

Comment: @OdatNurd yes I am

Comment: What packages have you installed so far?